# Cannot connect to P by ssh i: Operation times out

Tags: ssh, static-ip

I set the static eth0 IP Address in my Pi by editing `/etc/dhcpcd.conf file` in my house

So i can connect in that address by ssh in my house(my Macbook is on wifi same router

but when i try to connect outside like cafe i cannot connect by ssh

and it said Operation timed out. what's the problem?

Comment: Sounds like you need to port forward ssh port on your router. Make sure you change your default pi password or your Pi will get hacked.

Answer (score -1):

Had similar problem, latest raspbian versions disable ssh by default.  If you don't have screen/keyboard to start ssh by hand and add it to default init, then the easiest way is to mount the sd card on a computer and create a blank fine name ssh on the root fs. (source:[ssh raspi documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/)

Comment: Question says it works in their house - not from outside